# Facebook social reading plugin for Wordpress?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

As you know, a lot of bigger news websites have intorduced "social readers" for Facebook (e.g. https://apps.facebook.com/wpsocialreader/), which log what the user has read into the activity stream ("Michael read..."). Is it possible to integrate similar functionality into a Wordpress blog? Are the relevant API's open? Are there any plugins available? Thanks.

UPD: http://trac.ahwebdev.fr/projects/facebook-awd
The plugin seems to do the trick. Will have to try it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, all of the APIs required to recreate the WashPo Reader or the Guardian reader etc are open, so it shouldn't be an issue to implement it for Wordpress.

Here's the relevant docs - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Answer (score 0):

i am the creator of Facebook AWD.

From now to get actions publishing working with Facebook AWD and wordpress you must buy a subplugin.
This process will take place with the v1.3 of Facebook AWD

**Update: The plugin is ready here: http://facebook-awd.ahwebdev.fr/plugins/opengraph-actions/**

Answer (score 0):

Came across this post while searching for something related. Anyone still thinking of integrating Social read with any blog or website can simply use this plugin(For non-developers or for developers who just want to use a ready made solution)..
http://sharethis.com/publishers/get-sharenow